# Inserir gif 'carregando' enquanto executa função

Tags: php, javascript

Possuo um botão de submit dentro de um form, que envia uma action para outro arquivo de funções. Neste arquivo funcoes.php vai executar uma função e retornará para a página atual. Enquanto executa esta função, após clicar em atualizar, gostaria de inserir um gif animado no centro da página para informar que está carregando. Como faria isto?

Segue formulário:

```
<form name="cdi" method="post" action="funcoes/funcoes.php" >
                        <h4><i class="fa fa-angle-right"> </i> Indicador CDI <h6>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; - Atualizado em <?= $dt_atualizacao ?></h6></h4> 
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-theme" name="cdi">Atualizar</button>
                      </form>
```

Comment: Você esta mandando via ajax ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Crie duas div's no seu html:

```
<div id="blanket"></div>
<div id="aguarde">Aguarde...</div>
```

Em seguida vamos aplicar o css:

```
#blanket,#aguarde {
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
}

#blanket {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    filter: alpha(opacity =         65);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=65)";
    opacity: 0.65;
    z-index: 9998;
}

#aguarde {
    width: auto;
    height: 30px;
    top: 40%;
    left: 45%;
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/SpJvla7.gif') no-repeat 0 50%; // o gif que desejar, eu geralmente uso um 20x20
    line-height: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    z-index: 9999;
    padding-left: 27px;
}
```

Depois com JQuery é só exibir a div no clique do botão:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.btn-theme').click(function(){
        $('#aguarde, #blanket').css('display','block');
    });
});
```

Ou se não quiser usar JQuery, com o próprio javascript no próprio botão:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-theme" name="cdi" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('blanket').style.display = 'block';document.getElementById('aguarde').style.display = 'block';">Atualizar</button>
```

Caso usar JQuery, não esqueça de importar a biblioteca.

Espero que ajude, abraços

Comment: 100% cara, obrigado :D

Comment: Também pode usar o as funções hide() e show() do jquery ao invés de css(). **$('#aguarde, #blanket').show()** e **$('#aguarde, #blanket').hide()**. Faz a mesma coisa mas usa menos código.

Answer (score 1):

É possível fazer uma animação "carregando" apenas com CSS (sem imagens GIF):

```css
@-webkit-keyframes spinning {
    from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to   {transform: rotate(180deg);}
}
@keyframes spinning {
    from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to   {transform: rotate(180deg);}
}
.square {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #999 #ccc;
    border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-animation: spinning 0.75s infinite linear;
    animation: spinning 0.75s infinite linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
```

Comment: Bacana isso ai, funciona em qualquer navegador?

Comment: é suportado pela grande maioria: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation e http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d, só não funciona IE <= 9